# How to handle self-reference in Spring Data JPA with Spring Boot 2?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jackson, self-referencing-table

I have a Spring Boot 2 application in which I have the following User entity:

```
@Data
... JPA and other annotations
class User {
    ... many fields including Integer id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public User createBy;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public User updateBy;
}
```

Now, the main problem I am facing right now is the self-reference of User (from User) and this either is causing StackOverflow Exceptions or InvalidDefinitionException depending on the certain annotations I am using on User. This issue is very common and several solutions are discussed over the internet which are:

**1. Annotate both fields with @JsonBackReference**
Annotating with @JsonBackReference omits the updateBy and createBy fields altogether, meaning I am not getting them when desired in my API responses.

**2. Annotate class with @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id") or None.class or IntSequenceGenerator.class or UUIDGenerator.class**
This approach works fine, until the serializer finds the same user object somewhere down the json and instead of putting it up there again, it puts a reference of that object based on the class selected above. e.g.

```
[
  {"id": 1, ..., "createBy": {"id": 2, ...},
  2 // <- Let's ignore how user 1 is created by user 2 and notice that instead of a user object, I get an integer ID reference.
]
```

This means, the client parsing this data will often there to be an object and not a number, causing parsing errors.

**3. Implementing a custom serializer (or extending an existing one)**
Now, I am really unsure if this is the right way to go about achieving my goals (mentioned below). But if this is the right approach, how would I go about handling this self-reference?

**GOALS:**

1. Serialize the data so that, at least certain fields in the child object (user) are passed back, preventing further recursive calls.

```
{
  "id": 1, "name": "old user", .. many other fields .., "createBy": {id: 2, "name": "2nd user"}
}
```

2. When the client sends a user object as request body, the application needs only the id of the child entity and not the whole object, as below:

```
{
   "name": "new user", ...., "createBy": {id: 1}
}
```

I know that self-referencing is integral to ORMs and there are a lot of use cases for self-referencing. But how do professional developers/applications handle this issue, especially in Spring Framework? If a custom serializer is the only way to go, how do I make it function appropriately?

Also, is it advisable to exclude these fields (createBy and updateBy) from EqualsAndHashCode  and ToString methods?